# Closed form for matrix with interesting pattern.

Tags: matrices, closed-form, symmetry

I have the following matrices $M_n$ with a pattern:

(shown $M_{25}$)
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&\\-1&0&0&1&1&2&2&3&3&4&4&5&5&6&6&7&7&8&8&9&9&10&10&11&\\-2&0&0&1&1&2&2&3&3&4&4&5&5&6&6&7&7&8&8&9&9&10&10&11&\\-3&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&2&2&2&2&3&3&3&3&4&4&4&4&5&\\-4&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&2&2&2&2&3&3&3&3&4&4&4&4&5&\\-5&-2&-2&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&2&2&2&2&3&3&3&3&4&4&4&4&5&\\-6&-2&-2&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&2&2&2&2&3&3&3&3&4&4&4&4&5&\\-7&-3&-3&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2&\\-8&-3&-3&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2&\\-9&-4&-4&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2&\\-10&-4&-4&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2&\\-11&-5&-5&-2&-2&-2&-2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2&\\-12&-5&-5&-2&-2&-2&-2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2&\\-13&-6&-6&-2&-2&-2&-2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2&\\-14&-6&-6&-2&-2&-2&-2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2&\\-15&-7&-7&-3&-3&-3&-3&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\-16&-7&-7&-3&-3&-3&-3&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\-17&-8&-8&-3&-3&-3&-3&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\-18&-8&-8&-3&-3&-3&-3&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\-19&-9&-9&-4&-4&-4&-4&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\-20&-9&-9&-4&-4&-4&-4&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\-21&-10&-10&-4&-4&-4&-4&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\-22&-10&-10&-4&-4&-4&-4&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\-23&-11&-11&-5&-5&-5&-5&-2&-2&-2&-2&-2&-2&-2&-2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\
\end{pmatrix}

there are blocks of sizes of powers of $2$, then consecutive numbers appear $2^i$ times, where $i$ is the current number of bits in the row number.

Any idea how to obtain a closed form or recursive expression for $M_{i,j}$? It is obvious that $M_{i,j} = -M_{j,i}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed form can be obtained as follows:
For $i\leq j$ it is:

$$
M_{i,j} = \left\lfloor\frac{j}{2^{\left\lfloor \log_2(i)\right\rfloor}}\right\rfloor - 1
$$

and $M_{i,j}=-M_{j,i}$ for $i>j$.